# Is there a way to fix this Sprintf problem

Tags: php, html

I Have this code it works well but cuts the message after the code line:

```
message=Sprintf("<p>Dear user,<br />
Your request have been initiated from your Account. Enter your code <br /><br />
Your Code is: %u", $data['code'], 
================================================Doesn't send this part below
"Your Code will expire in 30 minutes, 
Thank you for choosing Industrial Bank, we are determined to making life better for you.<br />
<br /><br />
Regards,<br />
Apptix<br />
")
```

I have tried creating another variable with the problematic part.

```
message=Sprintf("<p>Dear user,<br />
Your  transfer request have been initiated from your Private Account. Enter your code <br /><br />
Your Code is: %u", $data['code'] <br /> <br /> 
"Your Code will expire in 30 minutes, 
Thank you for choosing Industrial Bank, we are determined to making life better for you.<br />
<br /><br />
Regards,<br />
Apptix<br />
")
```

Comment: PHP variables start with a dollar sign...

Comment: PHP commands are terminated with a semi-colon...

Comment: You usage of [sprintf()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php) is invalid. (click the link to see how it should be used.)

Comment: Just use `echo`... or string concatenation.

Answer (score 1):

The first argument to sprintf() is the string template. You're attempting to use two separate templates, which won't work. You have:

```
sprintf('template 1', $data['code'], 'template 2');
```

You want:

```
sprintf('template 1 template 2', $data['code']);
```

Or perhaps:

```
sprintf('template 1', $data['code']) . 'template2';
```

Answer (score 0):

- initiate variable with dollar sign
- use sprintf function not Sprintf
- use %s to represent string in place of %
- u don't need comma after
  $data

  ```
  $mesage = sprintf("<p>Dear user,<br />
  Your request have been initiated from your Account. Enter your code <br /><br />
  Your Code is: %s", $data['code']);
  // output  $message
  echo $mesage;
  ```

after that, the $message variable will have $data['code'] content in place of %s